# vulnerabilities error while installing via NPM, ( npm audit fix ) also not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I was working on a react project and wanted to install react-icons so run `npm install react-icons` in the command prompt.
but after a while it throws these errors,

```
F:\Areebs\React JS\areeburrub>npm install react-icons
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.13.12 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ react-icons@4.2.0
updated 1 package and audited 1949 packages in 122.206s

138 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 85 vulnerabilities (82 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

So as you can see it says run `npm audit fix` so I did that also but,

```
F:\Areebs\React JS\areeburrub>npm audit fix
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.13.12 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 10 packages from 2 contributors, removed 3 packages and updated 3 packages in 22.668s

145 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 1 of 85 vulnerabilities in 1949 scanned packages
  84 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

---

#### I have tried these things:

after this error I searched why this is happening, and checked these.

- My NPM version is 6.14.12
- My React Version is 17.0.2
- My React Script Version is 4.0.3

---

#### One more thing I noticed,

the npm have installed the react-icons package but also showing these error, I tried to create another react app using `create-react-app` and there also it showed same errors.

Comment: This doesn't look like an issue with react-icons. You've got some warnings, and that's fine. `fsevents` is a Unix issue, so I'm assuming you're on Windows. The issues appear to be coming from those _other_ 1949 packages that have vulnerabilities. If you just run `npm audit` you should get all the information you need.

Comment: @Andy yeah I got all the vulnerabilities but how to solve these 1949 packages.

Comment: These are warnings, not errors.

Comment: @JBallin I got that few hours ago but why these warnings and how to fix?

Comment: You don’t need to fix them. If you want to better understand them you’ll need to read and research about each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try running **npm init** before **npm install**.